# MPMoviePlayer view issue when coming out of full screen

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayer

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for showing video inside UIView and using the code below:

```
self.moviePlayerSmall = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL:self.objUrl )
self.moviePlayerSmall.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds
self.videoView.addSubview(self.moviePlayerSmall.view)
self.moviePlayerSmall.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]


for subV: UIView in self.moviePlayerSmall.view.subviews {
    subV.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
self.moviePlayerSmall.fullscreen = false
self.moviePlayerSmall.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Default
self.moviePlayerSmall.scalingMode = .AspectFill
```

Where videoview is the UIView in which I am adding the MPMoviePlayer view.

The issue I am facing is that whenever the video player comes out of full screen then the player view shows spacing on the left and right sides.

I have tried setting up contentmode, ScaleMode and even AutorezingMask but nothing is working. Have anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated. Use autolayout, not autoresizing mask. Use View Debugging to understand how the view is sized.

Comment: The thing is that i have also used third party library which is supported with MPMovieplayer. If i remove MPMoviePlayer then i have to do lot of rework on Subtitle thing.